# How to take rows of data in Google Spreadsheet from one sheet, and pre-populate another sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I've been trying to start a hobby/business venture and I started sitting down with Google Spreadsheets to document all of my raw materials/stock and how much each "unit "costs to use a in a recipe.
[INGREDIENTS Sheet (main datasource)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0siv.png)

The ingredients page lists all my stock, and is the main datasource for creating new recipes, and a cost-analysis.
[The recipe sheet should be dynamically populated, and be able to add more rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjl0n.png)

I just wanted to be able to populate the ingredients sheet, then simply create new sheet for new recipes, so I can then keep track of how much inventory I have, and how much a new batch will cost.

So, to simplify my questions:

**1. How can I click on a button and add a new "row" with ingredients populated in the columns?

2. How can I populate each recipe field with a drop-down populated by the ingredients data?**

Comment: Can you please provide an image or some starter code? Maybe I can help you out, but I am not clear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not a very active user, so I cant embed photos, but I did link some photos.

Comment: I see, but I guess what I am asking is do you already have the blue button hooked up to a script function? What information is it copying from the ingredients sheet? Is it doing it automatically?

Comment: Ok, so the blue button doesnt do anything. I need it to eventually create a row under the ingredients list, with a dropdown to pick the ingredient, then after that the other columns will  populate... based on the ingredient.

Comment: Ok. I tried an answer based on what I am understanding. I hope that helps put you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is enough to get you started. You need to click on the image and there is a drop down to assign a script. Assign the script addNew. Then open the script editor and create the function like below.

```
function addNew() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var ingredientCol = 3;

  //you will want to pull these values from your other sheet
  //check here for documentation:
  //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder
  var ingredients = ['pepper', 'salt', 'sugar']; 

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(ingredients, true);

  sheet.getRange(lastRow, ingredientCol).setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

I shared the document I was testing. Just open the script editor to see the code.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EowRjZeRxIy18ZyMekehc976AlTcx4tmfWeEDis79hc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks so  much! I'll give it a try, and see what happens.